# Copy a file from www to 'Documents' using PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I am trying to copy a file that is stored on the phonegap folder (www/default_files/file.txt) to the documents folder in iOS, so far what I got is:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSys)
{
  fileSys.root.getFile("file.txt", null, function(theFile){ // file exist don't do anything},
    function(error)
    {
      // file does not exist, so copy it
      fileSys.copyTo(fileSys.root.fullPath, "www/default_files/file.txt",
        function success(entry)
        {
          console.log("Success: " + entry);
        },
          function error(entry)
        {
          console.log(entry);
        });
  });
}, fileError);
```

fileSys.root.fullPath contains the correct Documents Path, the problem is how to access the www folder...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

This code works for me on iOS. This function implements a copy of the database file from /www folder to /Documents folder.

```
function copyBase(){
    var wwwPath = window.location.pathname;
    var basePath = 'file://'+ wwwPath.substring(0,wwwPath.length-10);
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(basePath+'myDB.db', 
        function(fileDB){
            console.log('success! database was found')  
            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onSuccess, null);

                function onSuccess(fileSystem) {
                    var documentsPath = fileSystem.root;
                    fileDB.copyTo(documentsPath, 'myDB.db',
                    function(){
                        console.log('copying was successful')
                    }, 
                    function(){
                        console.log('unsuccessful copying')
                    });
                }
        }, 
        function(){
            console.log('failure! database was not found')
        });
}
```

Comment: you can use `cordova.file.applicationDirectory` instead of the hacky www-path.

Answer (score 1):

you can access the www folder as below 
**/var/mobile/Applications/35----------------9087/yourapp.app/www/yourfolder/yourfilename.ext**

**edit**
use `alert(window.location.pathname);` to find the path of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [cordova-plugin-file](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/).
Then you can access the www folder using the string :  cordova.file.applicationDirectory+ "www/"
and Documents folder using the string:
cordova.file.documentsDirectory.